# Do we ever see Joey's parents?

Tags: character, friends

I remember *Friends* episodes with the parents of Monica and Ross. Chandler's parents also showed up in the early seasons, and there was a whole arc about Phoebe's mother. Rachel's parents also appear in multiple episodes.

I can't remember any episode with Joey's parents. Some featured Joey's sisters, but I can't recall if his dad/mom showed up in any of them.

Do Joey's dad and mom appear in any Friends episodes?

Comment: Why didn't you simply [Google this](https://www.google.com/search?q=friends+joey+parents)? First link is to the IMDb entry of ["The One with the Boobies"](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt0583582/), the second to the [Wikipedia page for Joey Tribbiani](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Joey_Tribbiani), fourth to [a piece on Vulture about all of the Friends' parents](http://www.vulture.com/2014/12/friends-parents-ranking.html),...

Comment: @BCdotWEB: Dunno, I just couldn't remember it and asking it here was my first thought. Guess I trust this SE more than Google! Anyway, I wasn't even sure if they showed up in one episode or more; or at all. If I was just trying to place an episode name, I'd have Googled.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Indeed, in [**Episode 13- The One with the Boobies**](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt0583582/), Joey discovers his father (Joey Tribbiani Senior, played by [Robert Costanzo](http://www.imdb.com/name/nm0182456/)) has a mistress and intervenes, forcing him to tell his wife, later in the episode, Joey's mother (Gloria Tribiani, played by [Brenda Vaccaro](http://www.imdb.com/name/nm0882853/)) shows up furious at Joey, as she already knew about the mistress and because of it he would treat her better out of guilt.

Comment: Ah! Yes. Thanks. Do they show up in any other episodes? I remember Joey inviting his parents for the Chandler/Monica wedding. Can't recall if they actually came

Comment: They came - in S08E02 we can see a weird present they gave,  'a salami machine', but they are not shown.

Comment: @Area51DetectiveFiction This is their only on-screen appearance in the series.

Comment: @CrowTRobot: You seem sure. Upvote.

Comment: Simply looking at the actors' IMDb listings should confirm that they are only in one episode... and the links are right there, all convenient in the answer and everything.

Comment: @Catija doesn't work because sometimes characters are played by different actors... e.g. by that logic, Carol only appears in one episode https://www.imdb.com/name/nm0056342/